# How to check all the special characters including 0 and except numbers from 1... so on)?

Tags: c#

I want to check all the special characters including 0 and except numbers from 1... so on. How can I do so?

I wrote the below code which works for the special characters but when I check for alphabets it works only for a, z and A, Z.

```
private bool checkSpecialCharacters(string Version1, string Version2)
{
    string splChars = @"%!@#$%^&*()?/>.<,:;'\|}]{[_~`+=-öüäß[^a-zA-Z]" + "\"" + @"^[a-zA-Z0]";

    char[] splCharsArray = splChars.ToCharArray();

    int Index1 = Version1.IndexOfAny(splCharsArray);
    int Index2 = Version2.IndexOfAny(splCharsArray);

    //index == -1 no special characters
    if (Index1 == -1 && Index2 == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect that `A-Z` checks the whole alphabet? That's not a regular expression. So either use regex or extend the list to include all characters.

Comment: Also, instead of checking against all other characters, why don't you check if they only contain digits? `return Version1.All(Char.IsDigit) && Version2.All(Char.IsDigit)`.

Comment: since in your splChars string you have only given a, A, z, Z it is checking only these four...you need to type all the alphabets out there

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to do. That is, I cannot tell from the description what the output should be given any arbitrary input.

That said, it *seems* like you might be trying to flag any string that contains any character other than letters from the Latin alphabet (i.e. `A` through `Z`, upper and lower case).

If that's true, then you could just do something like this:

```
private static bool checkSpecialCharacters(string Version1, string Version2)
{
    Tuple<char, char>[] charRanges =
    {
        Tuple.Create('A', 'Z'),
        Tuple.Create('z', 'z'),
    };

    return !AllInRange(Version1, charRanges) || !AllInRange(Version2, charRanges);
}

private static bool AllInRange(string text, Tuple<char, char>[] charRanges)
{
    foreach (char ch in text)
    {
        bool inRange = false;

        foreach (Tuple<char, char> range in charRanges)
        {
            if (range.Item1 <= ch && ch <= range.Item2)
            {
                inRange = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!inRange)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The above simply scans each string, checking each character against an array of character ranges. If it finds a character not in any of the allowed ranges, it flags the string as invalid (i.e. returns `false`). Then the caller will return `true` is for either string it was flagged as invalid.

An alternative would be to use Regex:

```
private static readonly Regex _alphaRegex =
    new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

private static bool checkSpecialCharacters(string Version1, string Version2)
{
    return _alphaRegex.IsMatch(Version1) || _alphaRegex.IsMatch(Version2);
}
```

The above does basically the same thing, but lets the `Regex` class do the work. An instance of `Regex` is created once, which is shared by each call to the method. The expression is simply `[^A-Za-z]`, which indicates that a match will occur for any character that is *not* in the set of characters that includes `A` through `Z` and `a` through `z` (i.e. the upper and lower case letters from the Latin alphabet).

In this version, if a character matching the expression — i.e. any character *not* in the specified set of `A-Za-z` — is found in either string, the method returns `true`, indicating a "special" character was found.

If these code examples don't address your need, then please fix your question so that it is clear what that need is. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.